# asterisk dial plan working fine with DTMF tones. not working with mobile phones

Tags: android, iphone, asterisk, dtmf

asterisk server is running with chan dongle driver.DTMF tones used here to change the playing audio file. here is the extension file.

```
exten => 123,1,Answer()
exten => 123,n,Background(main-menu)
exten => 123,n,WaitExten()
exten => 2,1,Playback(digits/2)
```

This extensions are working only if i use Land Phone. If i use mobile this DTMF does not work. how to use mobile phones with this? thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a programming question. You might get better luck at http://serverfault.com/. Just a hint: there are different ways to send DTMF with SIP, check that the Android phone and your server are one the same page about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're running into here is a common problem with Cellphones.  You don't give enough information to really solve your problem, though.  Asterisk IVRs that respond to DTMF from cellphones can be done (I do it all the time).

That said, If you are using VoIP to get the call onto your PBX, here are a few places you can check:

- Ensure that DTMF if carried to you via  RFC2833, NOT tone.
- Ensure that you are not using low bandwidth codecs like GSM.
- Verify that the cellphone you are using will work with someone **else's** IVR before you beat your head against the wall for what turns out to be a carrier problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm almost facing same problem. As I tried to make a normal call and pressing any key while the call but couldn't hear any tones from any phone to other, and I tried many phones with no luck however it's all working with any IVR perfectly. So can DTMF Decoder MT8870 module handle this DTMF signals? Also what about SIM800L and other GSM modules?